# How to set up a web server on the Raspberry Pi Pico W using CircuitPython?

Tags: webserver, raspberry-pi-pico, access-point, adafruit-circuitpython

I have a soft access point (hotspot) without internet connection set up on my Raspberry Pi Pico W see the code below:

```
# import wifi module
import wifi

# set access point credentials
ap_ssid = "myAP"
ap_password = "password123"

# You may also need to enable the wifi radio with wifi.radio.enabled(true)

# configure access point
wifi.radio.start_ap(ssid=ap_ssid, password=ap_password)

"""
start_ap arguments include: ssid, password, channel, authmode, and max_connections
"""

# print access point settings
print("Access point created with SSID: {}, password: {}".format(ap_ssid, ap_password))

# print IP address
print("My IP address is", wifi.radio.ipv4_address)
```

Special thanks to Alek V for helping me with this code.

Now what I want is to be able to join the network with my phone and go to 192.168.4.1:80 in my web browser. Now I tried getting the web server to work using a module called wgiserver, but I am not that good at CircuitPython and it just doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to set up a web server using CircuitPython?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    wifi.radio.connect(
        ssid=os.getenv("CIRCUITPY_MY_WIFI_SSID"),
        password=os.getenv("CIRCUITPY_MY_WIFI_PASSWORD"),
    )
    mdns_server = mdns.Server(wifi.radio)
    print("MDNS Hostname: " + mdns_server.hostname)
    mdns_server.hostname = "HOSTNAME"
    mdns_server.advertise_service(service_type="_http", protocol="_tcp", port=80)

    pool = socketpool.SocketPool(wifi.radio)
    server = Server(pool, "/static", debug=True)

    @server.route("/<path:path>", GET)
    def static(request: Request, path: str):
        """
        Serve files from the /static directory.
        """
        return FileResponse(request, path, "/static")

    server.serve_forever(str(wifi.radio.ipv4_address))
```

Put your static files inside a folder named "static" and you should be able to see them at "HOSTNAME".local